# Why not see this widget?Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have this page:

[link](http://bagelhousecafe.ch/)

On the right I put a widget which unfortunately will not see.

http://i57.tinypic.com/2cqxiqu.jpg

I put an image to see more clearly what is happening.The name of the widget is `"(arcade basic)Icon & Text"`

**Code CSS:**

```
.widget {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 90%;
  margin-bottom: 30px; }
```

Watch widget looks like my admin panel

http://i60.tinypic.com/15xwxns.jpg

Can you tell me please what would be the problem you can not see my widget?
CSS code is something you hide?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no content in your widget in the front-end. So there is nothing to show.

Comment: Yea, it looks like you have a url with no text to link the button with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
.fa {
  display: none !important;
}
```

On line 5048 of style.css. Remove that rule to display the content of the widget.